# Close window after print

Tags: javascript

I have a page that when it loads, I want it to open the print dialog, and then when the print dialog is closed, the window needs to close.  I have tried many things. I currently have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = PrintMe;
        window.onafterprint = function () {  window.close() };
        function PrintMe() {
            window.print();    
        }
    </script>
```

In Edge, this seems to be working fine.  I chrome, it's working some of the time, which leads me to believe that it's a timing issue.  Sometimes the page will load and the show the print box, and close when the print box closes.  Sometimes, the page closes before it loads.  Sometimes the page not close after the print box is closed.   Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to define onafterprint before onload or right before `window.print()`?

Comment: If you think that there's a timing issue, you should look into "async/await".

Comment: I tried moving onafterprint before onload and it seems to be working in Chrome, but Edge is closing the window immediately.   I also tried right after window.print, and chrome works good there too, but Edge will not close after printing.

Comment: Try wrapping `window.close()` with `window.setTimeout()`. Like so: `window.setTimeout(function() {window.close();}, 100);`.